# Expand TabControl if container is wide enough

Tags: wpf, responsive-design

I have a WPF window that contains a `<TabControl>` with two tabs.

Each tab body contains a single UserControl, each UserControl has a fixed width of 300px.

If the WPF window is over 700px wide, I want the `TabControl`'s pages to be displayed side-by-side, like so:

If window.Width < 700

```
<Window>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Left page">
            <UserControlLeft Width="300" />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Right page">
            <UserControlRight Width="300" />
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Window>
```

If window.Width >= 700

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition />
         <ColumnDefinition Width="50" /> <!-- Spacer column -->
         <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
         <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="Left page" />
    <UserControlLeft Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Width="300" />

    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Content="Right page" />
    <UserControlRightt Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Width="300" />
</Grid>
```

How can I achieve this?

I'm guessing I could create both the Grid and the TabControl in the XAML and subscribe to resize events and reparent the `UserControlLeft` and `UserControlRight` instances but it feels hackish and brittle. Does WPF/XAML have anything equivalent to CSS's media-queries?

Comment: Hey there, did the given solution work?

Comment: @almulo I haven't had the opportunity to try it yet, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can define two DataTemplates, each for one of the different layouts, and use Triggers to choose which one to apply to the `Window`.

Something like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SideBySideTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <local:UserControl1 Grid.Column="0" />
            <local:UserControl2 Grid.Column="1" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="TabControlTemplate">
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="One">
                <local:UserControl1 />
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Two">
                <local:UserControl2 />
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </DataTemplate>

    <local:RangeToBooleanConverter x:Key="LesserThan300Converter"
                                   LesserThan="300" />
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Window">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource SideBySideTemplate}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Converter={StaticResource LesserThan300Converter}}"
                         Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TabControlTemplate}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Style>
```

I've used a custom Converter to check the Width, if you wanna use it, it goes like this:

```
public class RangeToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public double? LesserThan { get; set; }
    public double? GreaterThan { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var number = System.Convert.ToDouble(value);

        return (!LesserThan.HasValue || number < LesserThan.Value) && (!GreaterThan.HasValue || number > GreaterThan.Value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**CAVEATS:**

- This is changing the whole `ContentTemplate` of the `Window` itself. If you want the `Window` to have more elements that do not need to change, apply this logic to a `ContentControl` inside the `Window` instead.
- Since the whole Template is changing, the current not-bound state of the controls inside the Template will be lost each time it changes, including keyboard focus, etc.

You may be able to use a custom `ItemsControl` to do the same and not lose the state of the controls, by just changing the ItemsPanel or something like that... But it's far less trivial than this solution. Tell me if you need to conserve focus or something like that, and I'll look into it.